# Shorten commands?

Tags: c#, command

Is it possible to shorten commands, such as...

```
this.ExampleCommand1.ExampleCommand2.1;
this.ExampleCommand1.ExampleCommand2.2;
this.ExampleCommand1.ExampleCommand2.3;
```

to

```
ExampleShorten = "this.ExampleCommand1.ExampleCommand2";
ExampleShorten.1;
ExampleShorten.2;
ExampleShorten.3;
```

?

Comment: What kind of code is this? What's a "command"?

Comment: How come you're accessing a member named `1`, `2`, or `3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ExampleShortened = this.ExampleCommand1.ExampleCommand2;
ExampleShortened.1;
ExampleShortened.2;
ExampleShortened.3;
```

Comment: Thank you! I could never figure out what the type was supposed to be.

Comment: Is there a way to globally announce the variable? I try to place it under the class, but var is unknown type.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, just over over the ExampleCommand2 part, and intellisense will tell you the type.